# grouping and printing the maximum in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, series

A dataframe has 3 Columns

```
    A                   B          C      
^0hand(%s)leg$        27;30       42;54
^-(%s)hand0leg        39;30       47;57
^0hand(%s)leg$        24;33       39;54
```

So column A has regex patterns like this if those patterns are similar for example now row 1 and row 3 is similar so it has to merge the two rows and output only the maximum as below:

Output:

```
 A                   B          C      
^0hand(%s)leg$        27;33       42;54
^-(%s)hand0leg        39;30       47;57
```

Any leads will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
(df.set_index('A').stack()
   .str.extract('(\d+);(\d+)').astype(int)
   .groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(max).astype(str)
   .assign(s=lambda d: d[0]+';'+d[1])['s']    # OR # .apply(';'.join, axis=1)
   .unstack(1)
   .loc[df['A'].unique()]  ## only if the order of rows matters
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
                A      B      C
0  ^0hand(%s)leg$  27;33  42;54
1  ^-(%s)hand0leg  39;30  47;57
```

Comment: Hi  @mozway thanks for ur answer but the output should be merging the two similar columns and in column A and the B AND C column should be maximum values so in tha case my expected output is :  A                   B          C      
^0hand(%s)leg$        27;33       42;54
^-(%s)hand0leg        39;30       47;57      instead of  A      B      C
0  ^-(%s)hand0leg  39;30  47;57
1  ^0hand(%s)leg$  24;33  39;54....Any guidance will be helpful

Comment: Looks like the output I have ;) does the order of row matter?

Comment: sorry i have forget to mention few other criteria..Actually the above code matches partial match and display for example  the row 1 and 3 is partial match so it take two digits from 1st row and 2 digits from last row and displays the answer..so and if column A has no match so the values should be displayed as it is ryt but the code is displaying B and C column as Nan for no match in column A and i forgot to mention about column D column D will always be constant so the code displays NAN for column D

Comment: A                                                        B                              C                              D
^0hand(%s)leg$                            36;21                      21;42                      EMC60
^-(%s)hand0leg                             24;45                      21;42                       EMC60
^-(%s)hand^0hand(%s)leg$        21;42;30               42;57;60                 EMC60
any leads will be helpful..thanks

Comment: When you have such operations and extra column you don't want to touch an easy way is to drop them, perform the operation, then merge again with the original data on the id column (here A)